# Preventing my birthday to be shown in other people's Google calendar

Tags: google-calendar

How can I prevent my birthday to be shown in other people's Google calendar?

I saw my contacts' birthday appear by default in the aggregation of my Google calendars:

[image]

I know I can unselect the "birthdays" calendar but I don't want my birthday to appear in any such "birthdays" calendar.

Comment: Is that data sourced from entries that you put into your own contacts list?  That's where all of my birthday data comes from.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Hide your birthday from your profile: [Add or change your birthday on Google+](https://support.google.com/plus/answer/1350405)
2. Nothing prevents your friends manually recording your birthday in their own Google Contacts and viewing it in Calendar.

Comment: Other social networks make it [easy to export events or import to a calendar](https://www.facebook.com/help/152652248136178/). You might want to check and hide everywhere you may have recorded your personal data to.

Answer (score 3):

To make the birthday of yours to be limited,

(i) Go to Google plus and then click on the wheel icon on the top and then chose Profile.

(ii)Now click edit under the basic information label listed under the about column.

(iii) Under the Birthday,you can set the view as only you so that it wont be listed under other Google calendar.